# How do I iterate over the return of an invoke() call?

Tags: java, reflection

This question is with regards to java reflection.

1. I have a loop with a method m inside.  m changes with each iteration.
2. m returns an array of some type that changes too(because we have a new method each iteration of the loop).
3. I need to iterate through each type and call a method named getRetVal().

The code looks like this:

```
 for(Object ro: m.invoke(argList[0])
    {
      getRetValMethod = ro.getClasss().getMethod("getRetVal", null);
      Object co = getRetValMethod.invoke(null);
      ....
```

Problem is, invoke returns an Object type which doesnt have an iterator

Comment: then cast the object to the expected one...

Comment: Are you saying that `m` changes each time through the `for` loop that you posted? Or each time through some other loop that includes the code you posted in the body?

Comment: this for loop is in another for loop that isn't shown.  That for loop causes m to change every iteration of THAT loop.  So we have a new method each time, and we call that method which returns an array of some type.  Because we call different methods, we get arrays of different types.  I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast to `Iterable<?>`:

```
Iterable<?> iterable = (Iterable<?>) m.invoke(argList[0]);
for (Object x : iterable) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Now you've said it's always an array of a reference type, you can cast to `Object[]` instead:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) m.invoke(argList[0]);
for (Object x : array) {
    ...
}
```

If you need to handle both cases, you can use `instanceof` to check which path to go down (or neither).

Comment: invoke returns the Object type.  At runtime it is always an array of some reference type.  When I try your code I get a "ClassCastException: myReferenceType; cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable".

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA: Ah, you hadn't said it was an array. In that case, cast to `Object[]` instead. Will edit.